# Mixing `sap.m` with `sap.ui.commons` Breaks CSS of FileUploader

Tags: css, sapui5

I need mobile UI5 only because of the [TileContainer](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.TileContainer). But including `sap.m` together with `sap.ui.commons` breaks the CSS of my good-looking FileUploader (button looses its formatting) and TreeTable (fonts are too big).

Seems like a CSS conflict or overriding. How would you suggest to fix this?

JS Bin sample: http://jsbin.com/faveli/4/edit?html,js,output

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Regardless of the solution, mixing `sap.m` with `sap.ui.commons` is not a good design as those two libraries are incompatible to each other. To find out more unsupported combinations, take a look at this topic: [ui5.sap.com/#/topic/363cd16eba1f45babe3f661f321a7820](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/363cd16eba1f45babe3f661f321a7820)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for the hint, Tobias!

The solution was to change the order of imported libraries:

```js
        data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table'>
```

the **sap.m** should stay before **sap.ui.commons**

Answer (score 2):

you are using the gold reflection theme. It is not maintained any longer.

If you are using bluecrystal it will look better
http://jsbin.com/nozimaxeqi/1/

Best regards,
Tobias

Comment: Hi Tobias! Thank you for your help + example! Actually, I am still looking for a way to make it look valid with this theme... My year-long project is based on **gold_reflection**.

Comment: If you are using the sap.m library gold_reflection will not work for any sap.m Control see http://jsbin.com/zovasahomo/1/edit if you don't need sap.m you should probably remove it